# How do I shrink a div like text on the side of a float?

Tags: css, html, border, overlap

I have an image floated on the right of my text, but I'd also like to have a "notice" div along with the text. The problem is that the notice div gets stretched behind the float. The text still gets the proper margin. As far as I've found out, this is the intended behavior, but I'm hoping for a workaround.

[image]

I'd like the yellow box to shrink so it doesn't go behind the picture.

The notice box has: `padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color:#FFFFE8;
    border:1px dotted #550;
    border-radius:5px;`

And the picture div has: `float:right;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #528a56;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:5px;`

Comment: add float:right; to the notice div or float:left; have a play with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
overflow:hidden
```

on the notice box.